# Interpreter recursive Polish Notation with tokens list

Tags: c#, recursion, polish-notation

I have interpreter that solve Polish notation. I have all operations and numbers in tokens and I have a list of tokens. So for example `- - 5 4 2` is a list with these tokens:

> SubtractionToken, SubtractionToken, NumberToken,  NumberToken, NumberToken, STOPToken.

Example tokens:

```
class SubstractToken : IBinaryOperation
{
    public Number Interpret(Number value1, Number value2)
    {
        Number c = new Number(value1.Value() - value2.Value());
        return c;
    }
}

class Number : IToken
{
    private int value;

    public Number(int val)
    {
        value = val;
    }

    public int Value()
    {
        return value;
    }

}
```

So, I cannot understand how to make recursive function to solve this problems. Because when I SubstractionToken.Inrerpret(value, value) I need to give the values from `numberTokens` what should be substract from itself, but what happen if the next token is an operation token? or we have `- 5 - 7 2`? I don't know how to implement such recursive function which will detect that the first operation should be made - 7 2 then - 5 and resultof(- 7 2), remember the results and back to the previous not done operations. Any help?

Comment: Sounds like you need more of a parser than an interpreter.

Comment: @stuartd: OP is probably trying to parse and interpret at the same time.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/math-equation-as-string-to-reverse-polish-notation-parser). I wrote this about 2 years ago as a learning project. It can certainly be improved, but it should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually do this with an evaluation stack which stores the results you've seen so far. When you encounter a number on in the input you push it on the stack and when you encounter a binary operation (e.g. '-') you pop two values from the stack, interpret them and push the result. Something like:

```
public static Number Evaluate(List<IToken> tokens, Stack<Number> eval) {
    if(tokens.Count == 0) {
        if(eval.Count != 1) throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid expression");
        return eval.Pop();
    }
    var tok = tokens[tokens.Count-1];
    tokens.RemoveAt(tokens.Count-1);
    if (tok is Number) {
        eval.Push(tok);
    }
    else if(tok is IBinaryOperation) {
        var result = ((IBinaryOperation)tok).Evaluate(eval.Pop(), eval.Pop());
        eval.Push(result);
    }
    //handle other cases
    return Evaluate(tokens, eval);
}
```

this could easily be made an iterative function if required.

Comment: No order of precedence, though. Not sure where that fits into the OP's scope.

Comment: Ok, What i need if I have also Unary operations? Would it be ok if I add `else if (tok is IUnaryOperation){
var result = ((IUnaryOperation)tok).Evaluate(eval.Pop());
eval.Push(result)`?

Comment: @IAbstract - There is no order of precedence in RPM. There could be in the source grammar but that would be handled by the parser.

Comment: Well, true, @Lee ... but the way the OP wrote the initial sequence `- - 5 4 2` must then already have been parsed from `5 4 - 2 -`. Otherwise the original sequence isn't written in RPN ... technically.

Comment: Thanks, but there is also another error in code here `var tok = tokens.RemoveAt(tokens.Count - 1);` it says that it cannot assign void to an implicity-typed variable. So `RemoveAt()` returns void, with what should I  replace with this code?

Comment: ok great, now question, what if we divide by zero? how to implement exception?

Comment: @IAbstract OP never metions **reverse** poish. Just that it's recursive and that it's polish (as in LISP/ prefix)

Comment: @Blabla - You could throw it in the implementation of the `DivideToken.Evaluate` method. Otherwise you could add a case in the evaluation function for `DivideToken` and throw if the second stack element is 0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to interpret polish prefix without parentheses so that you would have to know the number of operands per operator (no rest args). The STOPToken is redundant or perhaps just to catch to short or long expressions?

when you `eval` your list of tokens and it happen to be `SubtractionToken` you pop it from the list and run eval twice (one for each argument) and with the results apply your function and return the answer.

Example: If the tokens are `- - 2 3 4 X`

```
top is -, takes two arguments
  top is -, takes two arguments
    top is 2 
    top is 3, we have 2 arguments apply
  5
  top is 4, we have two arguments apply
9 , finished (X is left on stack)
check if X is the top to ensure the expression is valid
```

Perhaps the reson for stop is  `- - 5 X`

```
top is -, takes two arguments
  top is -, takes two arguments
    top is 5
    top is X --> throw exception since the stop token is illegal as argument
```

Now for a mutable data structure you just pop the tokens off, but for a functional version you'd need to return both the value *and* the tokens that still can be read and the second `eval` needs to use that to fetch it's expression or else you will read the same expression twice.